# Razr i: Using external memory as RAM

Tags: motorola, flash-memory

So [I've read a bit](http://tabletrepublic.com/forum/uhost2-u2/%5Bguide%5D-how-use-external-sd-card-internal-memory-3636.html) about making you external memory as the actual flash memory on Android but am not sure about doing that on Razr i. I'm not that familiar with hacking and technology, so I need your help on that. How can I know if the device has this capability?

I wouldn't use it so much for storing data. So I'm considering buying a 32GB microSD for speeding up, using more apps at the same time. Is it worth it? Can I use it as RAM?

Answer (score 0):

no you can't use Storage Memory as RAM , the only way to optimize your memory usage is to disable and stop any process/services within cache or running in the device